# Python warning unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode

I know this has been talked about in a few places on the web, but I couldn't find an answer so thought I would ask.

I have the following python code which calls a stored procedure which expects an integer, but I give it a non-ascii £ sign `u'\xa3'` instead, which makes it 'unicode its pants'!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
import config.default as cfg

conn = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=cfg.db_host,
    user=cfg.db_user,
    passwd=cfg.db_pass,
    db=cfg.db_name,
    use_unicode=True
)

curs = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    curs.callproc('get_user_by_id', [u'\xa3'])
    curs.nextset()
except MySQLdb.Warning, e:
    print e.message

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

The above will cause the following error because the stored procedure expects an `int` so generates a warning, which is returned from the database as unicode:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I set `use_unicode` to its default value of `False`, then I get the warning:

```
Warning: Incorrect integer value: '£' for column 'p_user_id' at row 1
  curs.nextset()
```

Most of you are probably aware of the unicode Exception issue with python being a little annoying (at least for me and probably non-ascii language ppl)

I found several ways of solving this:

1) override the `_warning_check` function in the `MySQLdb.BaseCursor` and comment out the line `warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)` (about line 117)
*- didnt like it as I would like to see warnings*

2) import warnings and then add `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=MySQLdb.Warning)`
*- doesn't really solve the problem of other unicode warnings*

3) Copy the `warnings.py` file to the root of my app and changed the `formatwarning` function to format the message as unicode:
*- seems the best solution so far but is a python core file!*

```
def formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
    """Function to format a warning the standard way."""
    # s = "%s:%s: %s: %s\n" % (filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)
    s = u"{}:{}: {}: {}\n".format(filename, lineno, category.__name__, message)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno) if line is None else line
    if line:
        line = line.strip()
        s += "  %s\n" % line
    return s
```

Surely there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a £ symbol to a method that's expecting an int?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - it could just be another stored procedure that returns a warning if it has truncated the message that had a french `é` in it. The focus here is really how to handle unicode exception messages in python

Comment: I'm halfway sure that these two things happen in different parts of the code, so they are different issues that you can research separately.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - probably, but when I normally write a question on SO, people ask me for more details, so I gave the full story this time :)

Comment: Its an error, the database was not updated, so you should handle it like any other db error. As for why it happens, its just a guess, but you haven't set the encoding for the database. Try adding `charset='utf8'` to `MySQLdb.connect` (or maybe utf16...).

Comment: @tdelaney - tried that. in fact that isnt really necessary if you put the charset at the top (i think), but setting the charset does imply use_unicode

Comment: the `#!coding` line only declares to Python the encoding of the source file itself.

Comment: @Christian - the charset at the top is just the encoding of the script file itself. Its useful if your text editor is, say, utf8 and you have encoded strings in the file itself.

Comment: @MarkTolonen / tdelaney - ok, still didnt fix it though :)

Comment: Where is the `UnicodeEncodeError` error raised? Is it on the print statement? Are you using the Windows command prompt?

Comment: @bobince - in the warnings.py formatwarning function. the line that is commented out in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a problem any more, possibly due to updates in the module or MySQL server - running MySQL 5.7.12.

I have also changed from using `use_unicode` to setting the charset, so my connection string looks like:

```
MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PSWD, db=DB_NAME, charset='UTF8', connect_timeout=5)
```

However, I was tweaking a high throughput application and found that normally the Mysqldb module requests the warnings after every execution which cost a few ms. But found that adding `curs._defer_warnings = True` to the cursor before executing, prevented this, and then you can use `self.warnings = curs._warnings` to get the number of warnings.

```
curs = self.conn.cursor(cursors.DictCursor)
curs._defer_warnings = True
try:
    self.affected = curs.execute(sql, args)
    self.warnings = curs._warnings
    if sql.lower().startswith('insert'):
        self.lastrowid = curs.lastrowid
    elif sql.lower().startswith('select'):
        self.data = curs.fetchall()
except MySQLError, e:
    if e.args[0] == 1064:
        raise Exception("MySQL Error [1064]: Error in SQL syntax")
    else:
        raise Exception("MySQL Error [{}]: {}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1]))
finally:
    curs.close()
```